# Инверсия однонаправленного списка на C++

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Возникла проблема при реализации алгоритма, который инвертирует элементы списка между максимальным и минимальным числами. Проще говоря, если есть список (2 1 4 5 12 5), то в конечном счёт он должен преобразоваться в (2 12 5 4 1 5), так как максимальный элемент = 12, а минимальный = 1. Создание, заполнение и поиск максимального и минимального элемента я реализовал, а вот как инвертировать то что между ними... это для меня проблема. Буду очень благодарен за помощь. Вот мой код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "conio.h"
#include "math.h"

using namespace std;
typedef float Tdata;

struct Tnode
{
    Tdata info;
    Tnode *next;
};

typedef Tnode* Tlist;
Tlist L=0;

void output(Tlist L);
void create_L(Tlist &L, int n);
Tlist min(Tlist L);
Tlist max(Tlist L);
void change(Tlist &L);
// Функция изменения порядка элементов между max и min


int main ()
{
    setlocale(0,"Rus");
    int n;
    cout<<"Введите количество узлов ";
    cin>>n;
    create_L(L,n);
    cout<<"Введённые числа: ";
    output(L);

    //Tlist L_min=min(L);
    //cout<<"Минимальное значение: "<<L_min->info<<endl;

    //Tlist L_max=max(L);
    //cout<<"Максимальное значение: "<<L_max->info<<endl;

    change(L);
    cout<<"Числа после сортировки: ";
    output(L);

    _getch();
    return 0;
}

void output(Tlist L)    // Вывод списка
{
    Tlist q=L;
    while (q)
    {
        cout<<(q->info)<<" ";
        q=q->next;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}


void create_L(Tlist &L, int n)  // Заполнение списка
{
    L=new Tnode;
    cout<<"Введите число ";
    cin>>(L->info);
    L->next=0;
    Tnode *q1, *q2;
    q1=L;
    for(int i=1; i<n; i++)
    {
        q2 = new Tnode;
        cout<<"Введите число ";
        cin>>(q2->info);
        q2->next=0;
        q1->next=q2;
        q1=q2;
    }
}

Tlist min(Tlist L)
{
    Tlist q=L;
    Tlist q_min;
    q_min=q;
    q=q->next;
    while (q)
    {
        if ((q_min->info)>(q->info))
            q_min=q;
        q=q->next;
    }
    return q_min;   // Возвращает указатель на минимальный узел списка
}

Tlist max(Tlist L)
{
    Tlist q=L;
    Tlist q_max;
    q_max=q;
    q=q->next;
    while (q)
    {
        if ((q_max->info)<(q->info))
            q_max=q;
        q=q->next;
    }
    return q_max;   // Возвращает указатель на минимальный узел списка
}

void change(Tlist &L)
{
    Tlist q=L;
    float temp1;
    float L_min=min(L)->info;   // Вызов функции определения минимального числа
    float L_max=max(L)->info;   // Вызов функции определения максимального числа
    while (q)
    {
        if ((q->info)==(L_min))
            q->info=L_max;
        else
        if ((q->info)==(L_max))
            q->info=L_min;
        q=q->next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С двусвязным списком было бы проще, но у Вас односвязный...

Идея алгоритма состоит в разбиении списка на 3 части, первая от головы до min, вторая min...max (его надо инвертировать) и третья хвост за max.

После инвертирования склеиваете их друг за другом. (Опять же, удобнее, когда список предствлен не одним указателем на голову, а двумя - структура голова, хвост).

Кстати, работать будет если min предшествует max в списке. Если не так, то указатели min и max надо обменять.

Оторвать хвост легко (естественно это набросок, всюду проверки нужны)

```
Tlist emax = max(L); Tlist emin = min(L);
Tlist tailist = emax->next; emax->next = 0;
```

С головой чуть хуже

```
for (Tlist p = L; p->next != emin; p = p->next);
p->next = 0;
```

теперь инвертируем

```
Tlist t = 0, inv = 0, lastinv = emin;
while (emin) {
    t = emin;
    emin = emin->next;
    t->next = inv;
    inv = t;
}
```

осталось склеить (после урезания головы p указывает на ее последний элемент)

```
p->next = inv; lastinv->next = tailist;
```

Теперь L указывает на первый элемент измененного списка.

Вероятно какие-то переменные можно сократить, и повнимательней, сильно не доверяйте, набивал прямо здесь, не проверял совсем.

Answer (score 2):

А чем инвертирование подсписка отличается от инвертирования всего списка? Почти ничем, правда ведь?

Поэтому делайте так:

1. Вычислите указатели на наибольший и наименьший элементы списка
2. Временно "оторвите" подсписок от основного списка.
3. Инвертируйте оторванный подсписок, и наконец
4. Вклейте его туда, откуда оторвали
5. В качестве бонуса подумайте, что делать, если максимальных элементов много? Например, все элементы списка равны между собой.

Comment: 1. Ну для этого у меня вроде как созданы функции min и max
2. Не могли бы пояснить, как "оторвать" подсписок? То есть если у меня в списке минимальный элемент стоит раньше максимального (к примеру), то я беру указатель на минимальный элемент (функция min) и работаю с ним?

Comment: @xeeqqw:

1. да, именно.
2. ну смотрите. во-первых, вам нужно взять меньший индекс из двух, это будет начало. ну и больший -- это будет конец. теперь, тот, который перед началом, указывает на начало -- установите временно в NULL. Ну и конец указывает на следующий -- установите временно в NULL. Отлично, у вас есть подсписок. Разворачивайте его.